MSAGL: How to do real time changes from code?
I am using MSAGL with WPF using GViewer. I need to change the graph without it requiring to redo the whole layout and without zooming out to the original camera position. I am working on an interactive tool and so the whole layout can not be changed abruptly.
Creation of a sample graph.
public void CreateTestGraph(List<FileOperationLog> fileOperationLogs)
{
    var graph = new Graph("complexGraph");

    graph.AddNode("A");
    graph.AddNode("B");
    graph.AddNode("C");

    graph.AddEdge("A", "B").LabelText = "Edge AB";
    graph.AddEdge("A", "C").LabelText = "Edge AC";
    graph.AddEdge("B", "C").LabelText = "Edge BC";

    graph.LayoutAlgorithmSettings = new MdsLayoutSettings();

    gViewer.Graph = graph;
}

This is what it looks like

When I try to add a node with a button:
public void ButtonPressed()
{
    gViewer.Graph.AddNode("D");
    gViewer.Graph.AddEdge("D", "A");

    gViewer.Graph = gViewer.Graph;
}

This happens:

The graph changes and the user view gets changed too. This is actually a minor change. When I try this with a graph of 100 nodes it gets changed completely after adding a couple nodes.
The best way I know how to refresh the graph is to actually assign the same graph to the viewer like his gViewer.Graph = gViewer.Graph;
I strougle with this aspect of MSAGL. It is hard to do things after the graph was created. You can do it with the mouse in the editor bar but it's hard from code.
I tried the normal methods of adding and removing edges and nodes. I tried Invalidate on the GViewer but it doesn't work. Methods like PerformLayout don't do anything.
